# Is there a way to further increase sampling rate in Python, if I were to use Qtimer?

Tags: python, pyqt5

There are several questions asked by this topic but, I think none could solve my case. Here is what I have. 
I have a GUI written in PyQt5. There is a function called `self.getValues` this function has some `if and else` conditions and then write values to a txt file. The execution time of this function is 0.0112. This function is attached to a `Qtimer` which timeout in every 10 ms. If I calculate it, it should write 80-90 values every second. But I get only 9-10 values a second. My overall program is too big, so I will post the concerned part for clarity.

**self.getValues**

```
def geValues(self):
 self.firstRun.append(1)
 self.t = np.arange(1,len(self.firstRun)+1)
 gyro2.updateGyroValues()
 gyro2.updateHeadings()
 xi,yi,xii,yii,zii,s1,s2 = gyro2.printHeadings()
 xiii,yiii,ziii = compass.axes()
 self.roll.append(xii)
 self.rollDrift.append(s1)
 self.pitch.append(yii)
 self.pitchDrift.append(s2)
 self.rollAccel.append(xi)
 self.pitchAccel.append(yi)
 self.timeTaken = self.timeStamp()
 with open(self.fileName+'.txt','a') as file:
    file.write(str(self.timeTaken)+','+str(xii)+','+str(yii)+','+str(zii)+'\n') 
 print(time.time()-st)
```

**Qtimer**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    timer_1 = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer_1.setInterval(1)
    timer_1.timeout.connect(ui.getValues)
    timer_1.start()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To my mind, the sampling rate is dependent on these two functions, if you think I am wrong, please give some suggestion. Also I should say it, my program has no issue other than speed. It runs and works. 
I will appreciate any kind of hint/suggestion.

Edit:
I am using multiple QTimer() and each timer is attached to a separate function. I was thinking that QTimer(s) operate independently (like threading). I tried to switch off all timers except the one mentioned above and it increased the update speed. So it means that I should use Threading.

Comment: Can you please modify your code so that we are able to run it? There are many variables that are undefined to us.

Comment: I think it might not be possible because the variable you see are coming from other python files. All these file run on Raspberry Pi

Comment: @mapf Since everyone one of these variable cause a certain delay, I can replace this with time.sleep() for you. And then paste rest of the program. What do you think?

Comment: Then you should try to come up with new variables that behave the same way. At the moment, it's impossible for us to run your code without having to guess what any of those variables might look like.

Comment: I fear replacing it with `time.sleep()` is not a good idea, since the time is what you are after. But you can try and see if it still produces the same unexpected result.

Comment: Le me try it to see how it goes. Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213317/discussion-between-juno-and-mapf).

Comment: Are the other timers also writing output to (or reading from) a file?

Comment: @Heike some are reading and some are plotting. But I think I have almost solve this problem, will update this question soon with my own solution. The problem is not in QTimer but rather I did not use threading.